# Renaming pdf files when being downloaded

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am downloading pdf files from multiple weblinks (one pdf from each) and want to rename each pdf file with a range of values so that they could be uniquely identified. I am using the following code but when pdf files are downloaded all the files are called `multi-page` and thus only one file stays in the folder. I would like pdf file names starting with 1 and adding 1 (+1) for each file next, that is, 2, 3, 4, 5 and so on).

```
import os
import time
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = ["http://example1.com",
       "http://example2.com",
      "http://example3.com",
      "http://example4.com"]

folder_location = r'K:/example'

for i in url:
    time.sleep(10)
    response = requests.get(i)
    soup= BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    for link in soup.select("[href$='.pdf']"):
        filename = os.path.join(folder_location,link['href'].split('/')[-1])
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(requests.get(urljoin(i,link['href'])).content)
```

Comment: this is an example of a clear answerable question with sufficient helpful programing support

Comment: I have not found any solution yet. I am instead downloading each file in a separate folder.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change the line:

```
filename = os.path.join(folder_location,link['href'].split('/')[-1])
```

to:

```
filename = os.path.join(folder_location,"{}_{}".format(i, link['href'].split(os.sep)[-1]))
```

**note**: the variable `i` should give you different names for each pdf. I also changed `/` to `os.sep` which is OS-independent.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it gives the following error `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'K:/example\\http://example4.com/pdf/multi-page.pdf'`

Comment: Oh, so..it happens that the server where the website is stored has Linux, while you are working on Windows. Because of this, there are both the separators '/' and '\' in the filename. As a workaround, change 'os.sep' back to '/'

Comment: The error still remains. I am copying the error message:
`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
     31         filename = os.path.join(folder_location,"{}_{}".format(i, link['href'].split('/')[-1]))
---> 32         with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
     33             f.write(requests.get(urljoin(i,link['href'])).content)

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'K:/example\\http://example4.com/pdf/multi-page.pdf.pdf'`